# SBT, how to add unmanaged JARs to IntelliJ?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, jar, sbt, unmanaged

I have build.sbt file:

```
import sbt.Keys.libraryDependencies

lazy val scalatestVersion = "3.0.4"
lazy val scalaMockTestSupportVersion = "3.6.0"
lazy val typeSafeConfVersion = "1.3.2"
lazy val scalaLoggingVersion = "3.7.2"
lazy val logbackClassicVersion = "1.2.3"

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "com.stulsoft",
  version := "0.0.1",
  scalaVersion := "2.12.4",
  scalacOptions ++= Seq(
    "-feature",
    "-language:implicitConversions",
    "-language:postfixOps"),
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % scalaLoggingVersion,
    "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % logbackClassicVersion,
    "com.typesafe" % "config" % typeSafeConfVersion,
    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % scalatestVersion % "test",
    "org.scalamock" %% "scalamock-scalatest-support" % scalaMockTestSupportVersion % "test"
  )
)

unmanagedJars in Compile += file("lib/opencv-331.jar")

lazy val pimage = project.in(file("."))
  .settings(commonSettings)
  .settings(
    name := "pimage"
  )

parallelExecution in Test := true
```

It is working fine, if I use sbt run, but I cannot run from IntelliJ.

I receive error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java331 in java.library.path

I can add manually (File->Project Structure->Libraries->+ necessary dir).
My question is: is it possible to specify build.sbt that it will automatically create IntelliJ project with specified library?

Answer (score 0):

I would say try to: drag and drop the dependency into the /lib which should be in the root directory of your project, if it's not there create it.

Run commands: 
sbt reload
sbt update

Lastly you could try something like:
File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> then mark all the modules usually 1 to 3, delete them (don't worry won't delete your files) -> hit the green plus sign and select Import Module -> select root directory of your project and it should then refresh it

If none of these help, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Thank you @Tadas V
As I mentioned before I can do it manually ((File->Project Structure->Libraries->+ necessary dir). But it means that everybody who use my sbt project will have to do same - manual settings. I'm looking for a way to do it automatically, just from build.sbt file.

Comment: No problem pal. Although if you were to add the dependency into the /lib and then add it to the VCS(shouldn't matter if it was github or bitbucket or other) you should be able to commit push it up and whoever then clones your project would get it with the project as well. Although you would need to check if adding it to the /lib would allow you to work with the dependency as expected. As after you add it to /lib it should become usable inside the project without any further configuration, unless the dependency itself requires it.

Comment: What @TadasV. said as first option plus closing and opening the project works well.